# How to correctly submit an array of jobs using slurm

Tags: bash, slurm

I'm trying to submit an array of jobs using `slurm`, but it's not working as I expected. My bash script is `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                      
#SBATCH --nodes=1                                                                                                
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                                                                                               
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1                                                                                        
#SBATCH --mem=10G                                                                                                
#SBATCH --account=myaccount                                                                                        
#SBATCH --partition=partition                                                                                      
#SBATCH --time=10:00:00                                                                                          
###Array setup here                                                                                              
#SBATCH --array=1-6                                                                                              
#SBATCH --output=test_%a.out                                                                                   

echo TEST MESSAGE 1
echo $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

python test.py
```

The `test.py` code:

```
print('TEST MESSAGE 2')
```

I then submitted this job by doing:

`sbatch --wrap="bash test.sh"`

I'm not even sure if this is how I should run it. Because there are already SBATCH commands in the bash script, should I just be running `bash test.sh`?

I was expecting that 5 jobs would be submitted and that `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` would increase incrementally, but that's not happening. Just one job is submitting and the output is:

```
TEST MESSAGE 1

TEST MESSAGE 2
```

So the `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` never get's printed and seems to be the problem. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with this but IIRC you should run the task with `srun` like `srun echo $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to submit the script with `sbatch test.sh`. Using `--wrap` in the way you've done it just runs `test.sh` as a simple Bash script, so none of the Slurm-specific parts are used.